# Python: logging disapears when in django shell

Tags: python, django, logging

**Running:** Python 3.3 in virtualenv, Windows 7, Django 1.6.5

**Background:** I am working on a Django project currently.  The projects directory has a python file `logManager.py` that configs the logging module, creates a root logging instance, which is then imported by the various modules:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                filename='logFile.log',
                format='%(asctime)-25s - %(levelname)-8s - %(name)-12s - %(message)s',
                filemode = 'w' # this makes the file clear before each new process
                )

logger = logging.getLogger('custom')
```

All of the modules that use this logger import it like this:

```
 from logManager.py import logger
```

Now I have an API module that's in a completely different directory, but it makes calls on the Django project.  It also has a config of the logging module.  This used to be in a separate file, but I recently added it to the api module itself, `logRequests.py`.  Here's the logging config code:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                filename='C:\\SeleniumTests\\APILogFile.txt',
                format='%(asctime)-25s - %(levelname)-8s - %(name)-12s - %(message)s'
                )

libraryLogger = logging.getLogger('')
```

**Problem:** When I use the django shell, `python manage.py shell`, which I understand to be basically just like a python shell with one configuration variable set, all of my logging method calls are not actually printing to the `APILogFile.txt`, they must be getting hijacked somewhere by another instance of the `logging` module. None of the calls throw errors or exceptions or anything, they just don't end up in the log file.  It's almost like they're being told to print somewhere else.

What can I do?

Comment: Use the `LOGGING` setting of django to configure logging.

Comment: @kroolik I didn't find `LOGGING` inside `settings.py`.  How would I configure it?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/